# RStudio normally launches in blank screen; requires sudo to work

Tags: ubuntu, rstudio

RStudio v1.0.136 running on a freshly installed x64 Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and R v3.3.2 launches in blank white screen with the below terminal output (see screenshot):

```
"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.desktopHooks.notifyRCrashed')"
QIODevice::read: device not open
```

[image]

But it works fine when `sudo` is prepended.

[image]

How this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try moving the RStudio session state folder out of the way temporarily?

```
mv ~/.rstudio-deskop ~/.rstudio-desktop-backup
```

If that works, I'm curious what the permissions on that folder are:

```
stat ~/.rstudio-desktop-backup
ls -la ~/.rstudio-desktop-backup
```

Do also look into the `~/.rstudio-desktop` directory ownership. Try changing the ownership to user by `sudo chown -R <user> ~/.rstudio-desktop`.

Comment: Terminal spits `mv: cannot stat '/home/rsl/.rstudio-deskop': No such file or directory`

Comment: RStudio normally attempts to create that folder as part of the startup process -- perhaps it doesn't have permissions to create that folder, for some reason? What if you manually create that folder (e.g. `mkdir ~/.rstudio-desktop`)?

Comment: It's crazy. `mv ~/.rstudio-deskop ~/.rstudio-desktop-backup` returns `mv: cannot stat '/home/rsl/.rstudio-deskop': No such file or directory` while `mkdir ~/.rstudio-desktop` returns `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/rsl/.rstudio-desktop’: File exists`

Comment: What is the output of `stat ~/.rstudio-desktop` -- is it a directory, file, or otherwise? It's also possible some bizarre permissions issue is biting here -- you might try `sudo stat ~/.rstudio-desktop`.

Comment: It's a directory. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/PHlEq) are the outputs of the commands you suggested.

Comment: It's surprising to me that everything is owned by `root` there -- does `sudo chown -R rsl ~/.rstudio-desktop` help?

Comment: Wonderful. It works! I am adding the ownership change command to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Fixed by reinstalling rstudio. The disk was almost full in my first installation attempt.