# Rstudio opens blank on user but works fine with sudo

Tags: r, linux, rstudio

I have a new archlinux installation and got rstudio-desktop-bin from AUR, as the project site says to. However, I get a blank screen (as below) when trying to open it. When using

> sudo /usr/bin/rstudio-bin

It opens normally. I tried to reset rstudio from this tutorial
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State

and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477131/rstudio-normally-launches-in-blank-screen-requires-sudo-to-work) question, the problem was solved changing file permission. Both did not work for me.

What could I do?

Rstudio when opening normally:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a suggestion that an update to electron may have caused an issue in the [RStudio community forums](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-startup-issues/129247/3). By disabling sandboxing, they were able to start RStudio as a user and it worked for me:

```
/usr/bin/rstudio-bin --no-sandbox
```

To make more permanent until the problem is resolved you can add a line to your .bashrc (or equivalent in another shell):

```
export RSTUDIO_CHROMIUM_ARGUMENTS="--no-sandbox"
```

There is also a suggestion in there about building from a weekly source instead. But this was easier for me so I can't vouch for it.

Comment: Where can I find the `.bashrc`?

Comment: at your home directory. If it is not there, you may create one